# Conexión Java a Oracle

Tags: java, oracle

ojala puedan ayudarme, hasta ahora tengo una clase de Conexion con el método conectar(), pero no retorna ningún resultado, al parecer hay un error en el driver, podrían indicarme cuál es mi error o que estoy haciendo mal por favor?.

```
    package controller;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Conexion {

Connection conexion;

public Conexion() {
    conexion = null;
}

public String conectar() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    conexion = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE", "User", "Pass");
    if (conexion != null) {
        return "Conectado";
    } else {
        return "Sin conexion";
    }
  }
}
```

Es un proyecto web, un jsp llama al servlet de donde se ejecuta el método conectar() mostrando el mensaje.

Comment: tienes descargado el .jar? además estas seguro que estas son tus credenciales: "NombreDB", "MiClave" ?¡

Comment: Si, tengo el ojdbc6, lo copie en las carpetas de Tomcat/lib  Tomcat/WebApp pero sigue igual, si, me conecto con esas credenciales desde el SQL Developer.

Comment: Por favor, imprime el stacktrace del error en alguna parte, edita tu pregunta y agrégalo. Sin eso, estamos tan ciegos como tú en descubrir el problema real.

Comment: Pon el error que te muestra

Comment: Este mensaje me muestra cuando intenta conectar:
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.Driver.OracleDriver

Comment: Es que haciendo esto: `return "Conectado";` no te va a retornar el objeto conexión que esperas. ¿No debería ser algo parecido a esto: `public Connection conectar() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    conexion = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE", "User", "Pass");
    if (conexion != null) {
        return conexion;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
  }
}`... además de verificar lo dicho en otros comentarios: driver, credenciales, etc.

Comment: @A.Cedano hay un atributo `Connection conexion`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Era problema del driver, lo conecté de la siguiente manera y funcionó, gracias a todos!.

```
public String conectar() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    Connection conn = null;
    DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@machine:port:SID", "user", "pass");
    if (conn == null) {
        return "No hay conexion";
    } else {
        return "Conectado";
    }
}
```